# Getting query selector value d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fairly new to d3js. I am trying to get the query value from the second input element and I am not sure how to go about it.

```
 <div id="rxn-input" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 464px; display: block;">
  <div style="position: relative; outline: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: transparent; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; visibility: visible;"></div>

    <input type="text" spellcheck="false" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); width: 100%; outline: 0px; border: 0px transparent; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; box-shadow: none;">

    <input type="text" spellcheck="false" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: transparent; width: 100%; outline: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; outline: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: sans-serif; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); z-index: 100; cursor: default; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); overflow-x: hidden; white-space: pre; overflow-y: scroll; left: 0px; top: 100%; max-height: 443.016px;">
      <div id="5MTHFt" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);"><b>5MTHFt</b> 5mthf_e ↔ 5mthf_c</div>
      <div id="EX_fol_e" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>EX_fol_e</b> fol_e ↔ <b></b></div>
      <div id="FOLR2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FOLR2</b> fol_c + nadph_c → dhf_c + nadp_c</div>
      <div id="FOLt2" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><b>FOLt2</b> fol_e + oh1_c ↔ fol_c + oh1_e</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button input-close-button">×</button>
</div>
```

Below is my attempt at getting the value:

```
  console.log("VALUE:"+document.querySelector("#rxn-input input")[1].value);
```

However, I am getting a blank value. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why not add an id or class in the second input?

Comment: @lilo, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this is generated from another package without the id and I cannot add an id to that.

Comment: Have you tried `d3.select("#rxn-input").select("input").attr("value")`?

Comment: @pmkro, thank for the reply. However, that input is a querySelector and does not have a value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the input will always be the second child, you could so something like:

```
const input = d3.select('input:nth-child(2)');
console.log(input.property('value'));
```

Comment: thanks for that reply. That almost did the trick. I am now able to get the possible query hit value, ie if the search was "fol" the input value shows "folr2". However, I would like to set the search query .ie 'fol'.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what's going on with this other package that's generating the base of your DOM code, and why something is getting appended to the input value. But if you know the input will always have 'r2' appended, I guess you could use RegEx or built-in string functions to trim it off. Something like: `const value = 'folr2';` and
`const result = value.slice(0, -2);`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for that. One thing further, if I had to set that property value, would I do it like this: `input.property('value','fol')`?

Comment: Yep. You can also pass a function as the second parameter, if that becomes useful, e.g. `input.property('value', function () { return 'fol'; })`

Comment: is there a way to access all the property keys associated with that object?

Comment: Per the [d3-selection documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection), you should be able to access the current DOM element with `this`: `input.property('value', function () { console.log(this); })`.